# SQL Query to Calculate the Consumption Readings listed in 30min intervals, needs to be order by Date Time stamp and meter Serial Number DESC

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select, difference

Hi Stack Overflow Members :)

---

I need to get the consumption for each rows forward active reading.
Put the difference in a consumption column.
The difference is per each 30 min interval. eg; 17897352 - 17897335 = 17 as [consumption/30min]
But i don't want to group it by Date but it needs to be ordered by Date Time Stamp DESC.

---

Sample Table Content:

```
DeviceReadingID MeterRefID  DateTimeStamp   ForwardActiveReading  
284729948   ELON102582  2020-07-01 00:00:00.000 17897352
284756341   ELON102582  2020-06-30 23:30:00.000 17897335
284746613   ELON102582  2020-06-30 23:00:00.000 17897319
284710326   ELON102582  2020-06-30 22:30:00.000 17897303
284743959   ELON102582  2020-06-30 22:00:00.000 17897286
284762422   ELON102582  2020-06-30 21:30:00.000 17897270
284739309   ELON102582  2020-06-30 21:00:00.000 17897253
284758349   ELON102582  2020-06-30 20:30:00.000 17897237
284675646   ELON102582  2020-06-30 20:00:00.000 17897220
284686333   ELON102582  2020-06-30 19:30:00.000 17897204
284559642   ELON102582  2020-06-30 19:00:00.000 17897187
284560601   ELON102582  2020-06-30 18:30:00.000 17897171
284659743   ELON102582  2020-06-30 18:00:00.000 17897154
284657476   ELON102582  2020-06-30 17:30:00.000 17897111
284655871   ELON102582  2020-06-30 17:00:00.000 17897055
284636705   ELON102582  2020-06-30 16:30:00.000 17896998
284653158   ELON102582  2020-06-30 16:00:00.000 17896941
284624220   ELON102582  2020-06-30 15:30:00.000 17896885
284619064   ELON102582  2020-06-30 15:00:00.000 17896828
```

Thank you, I would really appreciate help with the above.
I cant seem to figure out how to do it

I was trying to use the below as an example but it didnt help

```
        WITH    SampleData  AS
    (
            SELECT  [TimeStamp], [MeterID], [Count]
            FROM    (   VALUES
                        ('2013-09-28 00:00:10', 'BA123', 1453.034),
                        ('2013-09-28 00:01:12', 'BA123', 1454.770),
                        ('2013-09-28 00:00:14', 'BB777', 2351.000),
                        ('2013-09-28 23:59:50', 'BA123', 1470.120),
                        ('2013-09-29 00:00:05', 'BA123', 1470.445)
                    )   AS SampleData([TimeStamp], [MeterID], [Count])
    )
    
    
    
    SELECT      MeterId, CAST([TimeStamp] AS datetime) AS [DateConsumption],
                MAX([Count]) - MIN([Count]) AS [CountConsumption]
    FROM        SampleData
    GROUP BY    MeterID, CAST([TimeStamp] AS datetime)
    --WITH ROLLUP
```

---

I want to do a Select Query that would give me the below result:

[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is adding a Consumption column to the Sample table output

```
select *, ForwardActiveReading - lead(ForwardActiveReading, 1, 0) over(order by DateTimeStamp desc)
from yourtable
order by DateTimeStamp desc
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you the above worked in one of my tables but i"m getting this error in the other:

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 7
'lead' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: i was running it as seen below:

SELECT [DeviceReadingID]
      ,[MeterRefID]
      ,[DateTimeStamp]
      ,[ForwardActiveReading]
      ,[ImportReactiveReading]
   ,[Consumption] = [ForwardActiveReading] - lead([ForwardActiveReading], 1, 0) over(order by [DateTimeStamp] desc)
      ,[KVA]
  FROM [sample_table]
  where [MeterRefID] = 'ELON115149'
  and [DateTimeStamp] between '2020-06-01 00:00:00' and '2020-06-30 00:00:00'
  ORDER By [DateTimeStamp] DESC

Comment: Do the 2 tables belong the same database?
LEAD and LAG functions require SQL Server 2012 or above tu run, and the database to be at least SQL Server 2012 compatible.
Could you run the following request and check that the value for your database is greater or equal than 110:
SELECT name, compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases;

There is a similar discussion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338569/lag-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name

Comment: HI, Thank you i had realized that the one server i was running it from is 2008 which was apparently upgraded to 2012, but the Lead and Lag functions aren't available.

Do you perhaps know how to do it with an inner join to the same table as an alternative?

Comment: CTE and ROW_NUMBER should be fine with MSSQL2008; with CTE as(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by DateTimeStamp desc) as rn 
    from yourtable 
)
select T1.*, T1.ForwardActiveReading - T2.ForwardActiveReading
from CTE T1
inner join CTE T2
on T1.rn = T2.rn - 1